# How to pass a variable in php between pages automatically (without using Form Inputs)

Tags: php, variables

I want to pass variable from one page to another say `$id` from page1 to page2 but I want that to happen automatically without hitting submit button like in `$_POST` or `$_GET` method. How to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at `SESSIONS`? http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: already using sessions and cookies that carry some other variables.  isn't there any other way

Comment: Post your code then it's unclear what you are asking currently..

Comment: via the querystring - ie: `?id=404` ~ doesn't require a form. Sessions, cookies also do not require a form. Read from the db. Write to and read from a text file....

Answer (score 0):

Use php php session , you can set/get session variables using $_SESSION super global.